# vba highlight text in outlook email with HTML tags

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I'm struggling highlighting part of text in my email message. Message is assigned in a variable and later added via `.HTMLbody = message_variable`.

Below is the code and I need to highlight in yellow **"Please revert within 5 working days"**. No HTML background tags worked for me.

```
    msg_var = "<font face=Arial> <p style=font-size:10pt>" & _
              "Dear Sir/ Madam, <br />" & _
              "<br />" & _
              "MANY LINES OF TEXT" & _
              "<font color=red>" & _
              "Please revert within 5 working days" & _
              "</font>" & _
              "Best Regards, <br />" & _
              "</font>"
```

Outlook used is 2013

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used `"<span style='background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow'>"`highlighted text `</span>`

```
msg_var = "<font face=Arial> <p style=font-size:10pt>" & _
          "Dear Sir/ Madam, <br />" & _
          "<br />" & _
          "MANY LINES OF TEXT" & _
          "<font color=red>" & "<span style='background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow'>" & _
          "Please revert within 5 working days" & _
          "</font>" & "</span>" & _
          "Best Regards, <br />" & _
          "</font>"
```